# Center ASP Master Page

Tags: asp.net, css, positioning

First off let me say this is my first ASP.NET project I have done. I have tried using the center tags, encasing everything in a div and setting that to center, and the table tags with auto margin but nothing is working. Can someone point me in the right direction here?

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Server.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <link
            href="~/Styles/Site.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            type="text/css"
        />
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder
            ID="HeadContent"
            runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </head>

<body>
    <table style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;">
        <form id ="form1" runat ="server">
            <div class="page" 
                style="background-color: #000000; position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 160px; width: 1000px; height: 100px;">

                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Resources/image.png"
                        style="z-index: 1; left: 9px; top: 7px; position: absolute; height: 76px; width: 204px" />

                    <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" BackColor="#333333" ForeColor="White" Height="23px" onclick="Button4_Click"
                        style="z-index: 1; left: 931px; top: 65px; position: absolute" Text="Login" Width="60px" />

                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="White"
                        style="z-index: 1; left: 727px; top: 67px; position: absolute; width: 193px; text-align: right">
                    </asp:Label>
            </div>

            <div 
                style="z-index: 1; left: 192px; top: 165px; position: absolute; height: 445px; width: 938px; color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF;">

                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder
                        ID="MainContent"
                        runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>

            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BackColor="#003366"
                style="z-index: 1; left: 160px; top: 128px; position: absolute; height: 36px; width: 1002px">

                <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" BackColor="#336699" BorderStyle="None" Height="23px" onclick="Button5_Click"
                    style="z-index: 1; left: 220px; top: 7px; position: absolute; height: 23px; width: 60px;" Text="Users" Width="60px" />

                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" BackColor="#336699"
                    style="z-index: 1; left: 10px; top: 7px; position: absolute; height: 23px; width: 60px;" Text="Home" BorderStyle="None" onclick="Button1_Click"/>

                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" BackColor="#336699"
                    style="z-index: 1; left: 80px; top: 7px; position: absolute; height: 23px; width: 60px" Text="About" BorderStyle="None" onclick="Button2_Click" />

                <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" BackColor="#336699" BorderStyle="None" 
                    style="z-index: 1; left: 150px; top: 7px; position: absolute" Text="Profile" Height="23px" onclick="Button3_Click" Width="60px" />

                <asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" BackColor="#336699" BorderStyle="None" 
                    style="z-index: 1; left: 290px; top: 7px; position: absolute" Text="Servers" Height="23px" onclick="Button6_Click" Width="60px" />
            </asp:Panel>
        </form>
        <div style="z-index: 1; left: 160px; top: 165px; position: absolute; height: 445px; width: 32px; background-color: #FFFFFF;">
        </div>

        <div style="z-index: 1; left: 1130px; top: 165px; position: absolute; height: 445px; width: 32px; background-color: #FFFFFF;">
        </div>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently I have the `<table style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;">` but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Is the content for sure left-aligned?  Or is it just filling up the whole width of the screen?

Comment: Well it doesn't move. Like if you take this stackoverflow page and stretch it across your monitor it remains in the middle of the browser. My page remains on the left of the browser.

Comment: Very bad code. Get rid of all those inline styles in the first place. Then it will be more easier to read and you'll be more likely to find the problem. And NEVER EVER use table for web design!!! This has nothing to do with C#, nor with asp.net! This is only css and html.

Comment: I agree; but it might be better to tag it with asp.net at least, so that anyone else searching for asp.net master page centering would find it. Also; tables are fine. Just *not* for positioning!

Comment: I know it is not great code but I am just trying to get it working now then I will go back and clean everything later.

Comment: Also, you have a lot of absolute positioning set inline. You should get rid of this as it may override any additional positioning you try to do.

Comment: Axis, you're just adding work for yourself. As has dash already mentioned, inline styles override your external css, so it may be a source of frustration later when you will try to figure out why something else doesn't work again... Not even mentioning that pain when you will try to refactor this or try to modify. If you're "just trying to make it work", do it properly from the beginning, don't leave it "i'll fix that later". Just my 2 cents...

Comment: Yeah I decided to do that I have started redoing it already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you have absolute positioning set on your `div` with the `class="page"` attribute. Remove this as it will always position your div at `top:10px; left:160px`;

In fact, you have a lot of absolute positioning - you don't really need it and should get rid of it. Did you use Visual Studio or similar to design this page? Some tools are guilty of adding this additional CSS from time to time.

When I want to achieve centering I usually use a DIV with a defined width; I can then use the left attribute and a margin to simulate center aligned content. This also tends to work on a wide variety of browsers, especially older versions of Internet Explorer.

if you declare a div:

```
<div id="PageContainer">


</div>
```

and then use the following CSS:

```
#PageContainer{
    position:               absolute;
    float:                  left;
    left:                   50%; 
    top:                    20x;
    width:                  500px;
    margin:                 0px 0px 0px -250px; /* half of the width */
    background-color:       red;
}
```

Then it will center any content within the div. Defining the width and then setting the margin to be half the width is the key when using this technique.

[See a live example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/8wGNy/)

Stack Overflow use a more modern approach - it's the one you have attempted, but the key is that you need a width to be defined. By inspecting the CSS for StackOverflow (using the IE developer toolbar or firebug or similar), if, we look at the CSS for the header `div` tag, we see:

```
#header{
    width:    960px;
    height:   120px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

i.e. setting a `width` and then setting `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto` should be enough.

Comment: No problems; jsfiddle is also an awesome site for just trying things out - if you can create some basic HTML that does what you want to do, then you are nearly all the way there most of the time. Unless it's IE6 ;-)